Triggering a CronWorkFlow from another flow
A workflow can easily trigger another workflow. I usually do this:
templates:
  - name: child-trigger
    resource:
      action: create
      manifest: |
        apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
        kind: Workflow
      spec:
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: param
            value: "some-value"
        workflowTemplateRef:
          name: AnotherWF

This way, I access another workflow, named AnotherWF, and trigger it from within this one.
However, what if the desired WF isn't a usual workflow template, but a Cron workflow? it usually runs (say) once a day, but occasionally I want to trigger it from withing another WF, thus giving it non-default parameters.
I tried replacing the 'workflowTemplateRef' by 'cronWorkflowRef', but the child workflow fails for invalid spec: spec.entrypoint is required. I tried adding an explicit entrypoint, as well as workflowSpec.entrypoint, and also tried to reference a specific template ('engine') within that cronWorkflowRef, but nothing helped.
The Cron is somewhat like:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow

spec:
  schedule: '0 3 * * *'
  workflowSpec:
    entrypoint: engine
    arguments:
      parameters:
        - name: param
          value: "value"
    templates:
      - name: engine
       ..........

I also tried to add an explicit entrypoint to the Cron (in addition to the workflowSpec.entrypoint), but it didn't seem to matter at all.
